# Remove rel='dns-prefetch' href='//maps.google.com' from wp-head

Tags: wp-head

How to remove this from WP head:

```
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//maps.google.com'>
```

I had this also:

```
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org'>
```

But, I removed it with this code inside my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'emoji_svg_url', '__return_false' );
```

Probably, this is added by one plugin [exifografy](https://wordpress.org/plugins/thesography/), which can show map of location where image is taken. But, there is just few posts with map, so having this on all URL-s is just one more line of not used HTML code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Resource Hints](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/07/06/resource-hints-in-4-6/) is a smart feature added to WordPress version 4.6. I think it might improve your site speed. But if you want to disable it, try this:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_resource_hints', 2);
```

---

**References**

- [wp_head resource hints](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L232)
- [wp_resource_hints filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_resource_hints/)

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 *  Removes <link rel="prefetch" for WP assets not used in the theme
 * */
function remove_dns_prefetch($hints, $relation_type)
{
    if ('dns-prefetch' === $relation_type) {
        return array_diff(wp_dependencies_unique_hosts(), $hints);
    }
    return $hints;
}

add_filter('wp_resource_hints', 'remove_dns_prefetch', 10, 2);
```

I would suggest to remove it only if not used in the theme, this is the helper function I'm using

Answer (score 1):

I did this by using wp_resource_hints filter and preg_match :

```
    /**
     * Removes dns-prefetchs links in header
     */
    public function remove_prefetchs($urls) {
        foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
            if(preg_match('/google.com|code.jquery.com$/', $url) === 1) {
                unset( $urls[ $key ] );
            }
        }
        return $urls;
    }
```

```
add_filter( 'wp_resource_hints', array( $this, 'remove_prefetchs' ), 10, 2);
```